# LockedFileException: failed to lock file config.lock for writing

Tags: git, jenkins, build, nuget, gitversion

I'm trying to run a dotnet build on my Jenkins build server. I keep getting the following error:

> C:\Nuget\PackagesCache\gitversiontask\5.1.3\build\GitVersionTask.targets(10,9): error : LockedFileException: failed to lock file 'C:/jenkins/workspace/Shared-Build/.git/config.lock' for writing

And sometimes this message appear:

> C:\Nuget\PackagesCache\gitversiontask\5.1.3\build\GitVersionTask.targets(10,9): error : LibGit2SharpException: failed to rename lockfile to 'C:/jenkins/workspace/Shared-Build/.git/config': Access is denied.

What interesting is that another team member can successfully run the build, without these errors appearing.

I tried to look online but no clear solution is available. This exception seems to be related to the gitversiontask Nuget package, but I'm using a fairly updated version of it. Did anyone ever encountered this error before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference, this is a serious issue with parallel runners in GitVersionTask: https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/1381.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was re-creating the `config` and `config.lock` (while keeping the worktree intact).

```
del .git\config
del .git\config.lock
```

And then use this command

```
git reset --mixed head
```